# Spring RabbitMQ Could not autowire. No beans of ‘RabbitTemplate’ type found

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, version, autowired

"Could not autowire. No beans of 'RabbitTemplate' type found".

```java
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class OrderService
{
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;


}
```

When I downgraded the spring version to 2.4.5, it worked, but when I downgraded the spring version to 2.7.5, I reported an error, but the program still runs normally

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version> <!--Modify to 2.7.5 and it will no longer run-->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbitMq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-rabbitMq</name>
    <description>spring-rabbitMq</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```